# code always returning NAN

Tags: javascript

I am currently taking an intro to coding class and we are working with JS. My code is good but I am missing something because for the discount outputs I always get NAN. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
//Input
var orderAmount = prompt("What is the order amount?");
var contractor = prompt("Are you a contractor? yes/no?");
var employee = prompt("Are you an employee? yes/no?");
var age = prompt("How old are you?");
//Constant
var employeeDisc = .10;
var largeOrderDisc = .05;
var contractorDisc = .20;
var taxRate = .08;
var noTax = 0;
//Calculations
    if (orderAmount >= 800) {
        var discounta = orderAmount * largeOrderdisc;
    }else {
        var discounta = 0;
    }
    if (contractor == "yes") {
        var discountc = orderAmount * contractorDisc;
    }else if(contractor == "no") {
        var discountc = 0;
    }
    if(employee == "yes") {
        var discounte = orderAmount * employeeDisc;
    }else if(emplyee == "no") {
        var discounte = 0;
    }
var discount = discountc + discounte + discounta;
var subtotal = orderAmount - discount;
    if (age >= 90){
        tax = subtotal * noTax;
    }else {
        tax = subtotal * taxRate;
    }
total = subtotal - tax;
//Output
document.write("Original Price: $" + orderAmount);
document.write("Discount: $" + discount);
document.write("Subtotal: $" + orderAmount);
document.write("Tax: $" + tax);
document.write("Final Price: $" + total);
document.write("Final Price: $" + total);
```

Sorry about the code not compiling. It is now fixed. The issue now is that my document.write are not writing.

Comment: Well, either `discountc`, `discounte` or `discounta` is `NaN`.

Comment: You should not compare like that, convert to int first: `"15" > "10" -> true; "15" > "9" -> false`

Comment: Please post working code (the current code doesn't even compile) and provide a fiddle to get more useful answers.

Comment: addition for all said above: `if (contractor == "yes") } else if (contractor == "no")  {` - What if user type `fgsfds` in prompt box? (Yes, user can be _this_ stupid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your else statements are now improper so the code won't run at all. Remove the expressions like `(contractor == "no")`
 Here is a fiddle to show it working. http://jsfiddle.net/bitfiddler/6fYvd/

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to perform arithmetic calculations and comparisons using strings.  [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) is "Not A Number", which is the numeric result of an arithmetic operation that fails (for example dividing by zero, or any calculation on NaN).

Note the use of numbers, not strings, below:

```
var employeeDisc = .10;
var largeOrderDisc = .05;
var contractorDisc = .20;
var taxRate = .08;
var noTax = 0;
//Calculations
if (orderAmount >= 800) {
    var discounta = orderAmount * largeOrderdisc;
} else {
    var discounta = 0;
}
```

---

Additionally, [`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.prompt) will return a string.  You should convert that to a number before performing your calculations.  You probably want to use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FFunctions#parseInt_and_parseFloat_functions) or [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FFunctions#parseInt_and_parseFloat_functions).

Here is a simple example which produces `NaN`:

```
var x = 'x5';
var y = '2';
var difference = x - y;
console.log( difference );  // Note: you can use console.log() to write messages to the console in your browser's developer tools.  It is handy for debugging.
```

Comment: seems like JS will actually convert input to number here anyway.
`'5'*'2' -> 10`

Comment: '5'+'2' == '52', so don't rely on that.

Comment: Here - yes, but that will not produce `NaN`

Comment: JavaScript does have type coercion, but I avoid it.  I dislike the unexpected results that are often caused by type coercion.

Answer (score 1):

While you really should use numeric variables, JavaScript will convert the values as needed.  I tested your code and the real problem with it is these two lines:

```
}else (contractor == "no") {
```

and

```
}else (emplyee == "no") {
```

These should be

```
}else if(contractor == "no") {
```

and

```
}else if(emplyee == "no") {
```

The script won't even compile as posted, so I don't know how you're even getting NaN.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript NaN(Not a Number) is returned whenever you try to do mathematical operation on data which is not a number. You will need to check at which step it is returning string instead of number

Answer (score 0):

It's because you declare your discount variables in if clauses. Define them outside of if clauses, then you will have no problem.

```
var discounta;
if (a > b) {
   discounta = 0.1;
}
else {
   discounta = 0.2;
}
```

Also check variable scopes for javascript.

Comment: Actually, JavaScript is not like C or Java in that regard.  Only functions create a new scope.  Nonetheless, I agree with your suggestion for purposes of readability.